# How to update an existing Storm topology with new bolts in code?

Tags: java, spring, docker, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I'm writing a dockerized Java Spring application that uses Apache Storm v1.1.2, Kafka v0.11.0.1, Zookeeper 3.4.6, Eureka, and Cloud-Config all in Docker containers orchestrated by Docker-Compose.

The tuples I'm receiving with a KafkaSpout have a "value" Field that is a protobuf object. I use a custom deserializer to get my object out of it for processing.

I have a basic application working where I have a bolt that prints incoming messages and routes them to other certain bolts based on the value of a field in the protobuf object. I also have the LocalCluster, Config, and TopologyBuilder working as Spring Beans.

Currently I set all bolts in a PostContruct but I need to be able to dynamically add bolts that filter incoming messages based on other fields of the protobuf object and perform basic aggregation functions (max/min/windowed average).

I'd like to do this with a REST Controller but how could I stop and start the topology without losing data? I also would prefer not to restart the topology by listening to the Kafka topic from the beginning as this system will receive an extremely high load.

This article looked promising but I definitely want the entire process to be automated so I won't be going into Zookeeper https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/550/unofficial-storm-and-kafka-best-practices-guide.html

How can I edit an existing topology in code to add new bolts dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Storm topologies are static once submitted. If you need to vary processing based on a field in the tuple, your best option is to submit all the bolts you will need up front. You can then vary the path the tuple takes through the topology by using one or more bolts that examine the tuple, and emit to specific streams based on the tuple content.

e.g. make a SplitterBolt

```
public void execute(Tuple input) {
  if (tuple.getIntegerByField("theDecider") == 1) {
    collector.emit("onlyOnes", tuple.getValues());
  } else {
    collector.emit("others", tuple.getValues());
  }
}
```

where you in your topology building code would have something like

```
builder.setSpout("kafka-spout", ...);
builder.setBolt("splitter", new SplitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("kafka-spout");
builder.setBolt("countOnes", new CounterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("splitter", "onlyOnes");
builder.setBolt("countOthers", new CounterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("splitter", "others");
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So I'm doing something very similar to what you suggested already. I'm guessing from your response that if I wanted to add a new bolt to read from "onlyOnes" (like if I was going to sum all the ones together) that I would need to kill the topology, add the bolt to the topology along with the other bolts from before, and re-submit the topology to continue processing. I've looked at stateful bolts but I'm guessing the state is lost if you kill the topology

Comment: Yes, if you want to add a new bolt to the topology, you will need to kill it, edit the topology definition and resubmit. I believe stateful bolt state is lost when the topology is killed (but am not sure). Why can't you have the SumBolt in the topology to begin with though? You could use out of band messaging (e.g. through Zookeeper, see https://github.com/ptgoetz/storm-signals) to toggle it on and off.

Comment: Again, thank you for your help! The application I'm making must be able to create arbitrary aggregator bolts based on fields of incoming messages and a chosen aggregator. For example a user could make a REST call with a DTO that has aggregatorType SUM and filterName "num", then incoming messages that have a field "name" with value "num" will be accepted into the new bolt. So the bolt would sum all the messages with that name and publish the sums. The name could be anything and the aggregation type could be one of several simple operations.

Comment: So what happens when the user adds the sum bolt? Does processing start over, or does the topology just keep going at whatever point it was at? What if multiple users add a sum bolt? I feel like you're describing something that fits a batch processing tool better, where your REST call would be able to start up a batch job that would produce a result and publish it somewhere.

Comment: Another option, if you decide that you want to use Storm, would be to split your topology. You could use e.g. Kafka as an intermediate queue. So when your user asks for the sum, you can start a new topology that reads from Kafka and computes the sum (i.e. something like yourCurrentTopology -> Kafka -> userTriggeredSumTopology). That would let you decouple the part of the topology the user defines from the rest of the topology.

Comment: First comment: Still figuring that out. That's why I was looking into stateful bolts but there are a few other possibilities too. Storm may not be the best solution for this but I'd like to see if I can make it work with Storm.

Second comment: That's an interesting thought! There will be a lot of user created topologies though as I expect dozens, if not hundreds of custom aggregations to be created.